# How to let user set cursor position during Word Addin method?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, word-addins

I am trying to write a method for a Word Addin that displays a message box while waiting for the user to set the cursor to a position in the document. After hitting "OK" on the message box the method proceeds to insert some data at that position.

This can happen multiple times as the method asks the user after inserting data if he wants to insert some more data at another position in the document.

The problem i have is that the message box is modal and doesn't let me click in the document and when using a modeless custom form the code keeps running without waiting for the user input.

Is there a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem i have is that the message box is modal and doesn't let me click in the document and when using a modeless custom form the code keeps running without waiting for the user input.

As you already mentioned correctly a modal dialog won't work. A simple solution might be to make your form non-modal and insert the contents in the click handler of the OK button of your form.

A better approach might be to move your UI into a custom task pane which is displayed non-modal next to your document.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Dirk. I already have fixed the problem by listening to the FormClosing Event of the non-modal custom form.